# I keep getting the error "Group function is not allowed here" but no group function used, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am trying to run this query but I keep getting an error when it get to the count function saying "Group function not allowed".

```
select student.student_id,student.first_name,student.last_name, enrollment.enroll_date 
 from student
 left outer join Enrollment 
 on student.student_id = enrollment.student_id 
 left join Section on section.section_id = enrollment.section_id 
 left join course on section.course_no = course.course_no 
 where count(course.course_no) = 0
 and enrollment.enroll_date = TO_DATE('2/15/2007', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: `count` is a group function.

Comment: count(course.course_no) = 0  count is an aggregate function

Comment: how would I go about selecting students who are not enrolled in any course?

Comment: Rather than count, you should check whether course_no is found or not

Comment: "How do I go about selecting students who are not enrolled in any course?" **THAT** is exactly what you should ask in your initial question. Don't post code with an error and ask about the error. Tell us what question you are trying to solve. Then it's OK to tell us "here is what I tried, and the error I got" - but the first part of the question should be about the task you are trying to solve, not your attempt which may or may not even be close to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below query?

```
select student.student_id,student.first_name,student.last_name, enrollment.enroll_date 
 from student
 left outer join Enrollment 
 on student.student_id = enrollment.student_id 
 left join Section on section.section_id = enrollment.section_id 
 left join course on section.course_no = course.course_no 
 where course.course_no is null
 and enrollment.enroll_date = TO_DATE('2/15/2007', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: Let me know if it works

Comment: There were no errors when the functions ran but it returned 0 results so I'm not sure if it worked.

Comment: Can you please share sample data / ERD ?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` can't be used in `WHERE` clause anyway; you should move it to `HAVING`, but then you also need a `GROUP BY`. Also, get used to use table aliases and try to format it; make code easier to read. Something like this:

```
select s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, e.enroll_date 
from student s left join enrollment e on s.student_id = e.student_id 
               left join section t    on t.section_id = e.section_id 
               left join course c     on t.course_no  = c.course_no 
where e.enroll_date = TO_DATE('2/15/2007', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
group by s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, e.enroll_date 
having count(c.course_no) = 0;
```

---

To illustrate it (as I don't have your tables), have a look at the following example based on Scott's `EMP` table:

This is what you tried:

```
SQL> select job
  2  from emp
  3  where count(comm) = 0;
where count(comm) = 0
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

As I said, `count` can't be used in `where` clause. So rewrite it to:

```
SQL> select job
  2  from emp
  3  group by job
  4  having count(comm) = 0;

JOB
---------
CLERK
PRESIDENT
MANAGER
ANALYST

SQL>
```

Now it works.